# angular js Need help setting dynamic link in table

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set a link so it is dynamic, here is the function

```
$scope.prodFunc = function(){
            var tempData = "{http://###001dcpas01.##########.com, EVT-MQ-VNM:9102}";
            var config = {

                headers : {

                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'

                }
            };
```

I need the ###-MQ-VNM:9102 to be dynamic based on the table row. Here is the table data and the event.dcpName is what needs to be dynamic when check is clicked.

```
<table class="table table-bordered rest-services-table table-centered">
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">JVM Host</th>
          <th>DCP Process</th>
          <th>Health Check</th>
          <th class="text-center">Check Status</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="event in events">
          <td>{{event.jvmName}}</td>
          <td>{{event.dcpName}}</td>
          <td>{{event.status}}</td>
          <td ><a href="" ng-click="prodFunc()">Check</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>


<p>this is my first time posting so please be gentle :) Thank you,
```

Jim

Comment: what is the property that holds the dynamic data?

Comment: $http.post('http://#############.com/#########reportingclient/getDcpsJvmVerification', tempData, config)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.PostDataResponse = data; //post data response to use for table
                    console.log(data);
                })

Comment: This is all I have right now, data coming into the table from a get then posting back and a console.log to see the information being stored which right now always has the same value "EVT -------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data you need to your prodFunc function like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events">
     <td>{{event.jvmName}}</td>
     <td>{{event.dcpName}}</td>
     <td>{{event.status}}</td>
     <td ><a href="" ng-click="prodFunc(event.dcpName)">Check</a></td>
 </tr>
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
$scope.prodFunc = function(dcpName){

    // something like this string concatenation ??
    var dynamicLink = "http://###001dcpas01." + dcpName + ".com:9102";

    // this temp data doesn't look right to me vvv ?

    var tempData = "{http://###001dcpas01.##########.com, EVT-MQ-VNM:9102}";
    var config = {

         headers : {

             'Content-Type': 'application/json'

         }
     }
}
```

Alternatively you could do it like this with ngHref directive and skip the click funtion:

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events">
         <td>{{event.jvmName}}</td>
         <td>{{event.dcpName}}</td>
         <td>{{event.status}}</td>
         <td ><a ng-href="http://someurl{{event.dcpName}}.com:port" >Check</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I needed :)